# NSTableView not alternating colors

Tags: nstableview, highlight, xcode4.5

I am using Xcode 4.5.1 on 10.7 and am just getting started.

I wanted to have alternating colored rows in my table view, and was pleased to see the checkbox that would seem to turn this feature on.

I notice that while the table view is selected, the graphics show as alternating, but as soon as the table is unselected, it reverts to white. I have tried to "play around" with checking and saving to no avail. Is there a way to programmatically force occupied (or all) rows to alternate at run time rather than rely on the buggy check box?  Is this a known bug?  I have also noticed that if a shadow is cast on the table (from another window over it) then the alternating rows are noticeable...is this a clue? I can see this effect in the variable pane in Xcode as well, so it appears in Xcode itself, not just the created app.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, that was my clue... the highlight checkbox comes into play when the table is in shadow.  The many "alternating row" questions here address what I was hoping to do originally.